# How to limit number of documents returned for each term in Elasticsearch terms query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to get documents with specified list of terms, like this:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "md5" : ["file_1", "file_2"]
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to limit Elasticsearch results just to one document for each term? So as a result, I should have one document for **"file_1"**, one document for **"file_2"** and so on.

What I try to accomplish is to get Elasticsearch **_id** of the most recent document for each term in list. Can I do this in this way or it's necessary to do separate request for each term?

Comment: why it has to be one query? meaning can't you write two seperate queries with `size` as `1`?

Comment: because I need to get info about hundreds of files, and doing hundreds of requests doesn't look like a best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different ways to get the **N** documents for each term.

- One way is by performing one request for each term.
- The other way is by using the top hits aggregation (see the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)).

  ```
  GET /_search
  {
      "query" : {
          "terms" : {
              "md5" : ["file_1", "file_2"]
          }
      },
      "aggs": {
          "top-docs": {
              "terms": {
                  "field": "md5",
                  "size": 3
              },
              "aggs": {
                  "top_tag_hits": {
                      "top_hits": {
                          "size" : 1
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```